# is there a version of apache mod_aspdotnet for asp.net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, apache

or an alternative solution for running asp.net 4.0 in apache that doesnt require to install mono which isnt compatible with everything we use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the configuration file for Apache as follows:

```
LoadModule aspdotnet_module "modules/mod_aspdotnet.so"  

AddHandler asp.net asax ascx ashx asmx aspx axd config cs csproj licx rem resources resx soap vb vbproj vsdisco webinfo

AliasMatch "^/(?i)aspnet_client/system_web/(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)/(.*)" \
           "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v$1.$2.$3/ASP.NETClientFiles/$4"

<Directory "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v*/ASP.NETClientFiles">
    Options FollowSymlinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

AspNetVersion v4.0.30319

AspNetMount /ASP "C:/ASP"  
Alias /ASP "C:/ASP"
<Directory "C:/ASP">
    Options FollowSymlinks Indexes
    AspNet files
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.aspx default.htm default.aspx
</Directory>
```